Operator norm of some type of discrete Fourier matrix
Let $N$ be a natural number and let $w$ be a complex number.
We define  the $N\times N$ matrix  $C_w=(a_{k,l})_{k,l=1}^N$ as follows,
$$
a_{k,l}=\begin{cases}1 & l=k+1\\
w                     &  k=N, l=1\\
0                     & \text{o.w}
\end{cases}
$$
The characteristic polynomial of $C_w$ is just $p(\lambda) = \lambda^N - w $. Thus, the eigenvalues of $ C_w $ are just the  $N$-th roots of $w$ which are  as follows:
\begin{equation}
\lambda_k = |w|^{1/N} e^{2\pi i k / N} \quad \text{for} \quad k = 0, 1, \ldots, N-1
\end{equation}
The $k$-th column of the following matrix is the eigenvector of $C_w$ corresponding to $\lambda_{k-1}$.
\begin{equation}
F_w=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
\lambda_0 & \lambda_1 & \cdots & \lambda_{N-1} \\
\vdots &   \vdots   & \cdots &  \vdots \\
\lambda_0^{N-1}  & \lambda_1^{N-1} & \cdots  & \lambda_{N-1}^{N-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
If $w=1$, then $F_w$ is  the discrete Fourier matrix.

Q. Is it possible to formulate the operator norm of the matrix $F_w$ in terms of $w$ and $N$?


You can use the $F_wF_w^*$ argument to calculate the operator norm of the matrix. In fact we have that the elements of $ F_w $ are of the form $f_{kn} = \lambda^k_n $.
So the entries of $F_wF_w^*$ are
$$  \sum_{r=0}^{N-1} f_{kr}\overline{f_{nr}} = \sum_{r=0}^{N-1} \lambda^k_r\overline{\lambda^n_r} =|w|^{\frac{k+n}{N}} \sum_{r=0}^{N-1} \exp(\frac{2\pi i r (k-n) }{N}) = N|w|^\frac{k+n}{N} \delta_{kn}. $$
This is a diagonal matrix so its norm is the largest modulus on the diagonal. Hence
$$ \Vert F_w F_w^* \Vert = \begin{cases} N, \,\, \text{when} \,\, |w| \leq 1 \\ 
N|w|^\frac{N-2}{N}, \,\, \text{when} \,\, |w| \geq 1
 \end{cases} = \Vert F_w \Vert^2. $$
The last equality be the $C^*$ identity.
